# defclass type information for performance

Tags: performance, common-lisp, sbcl, typing, clos

In the following program, removing the line

```
    (declare (type (simple-array bit) arr))
```

makes running time increase by more than a factor of 3, using SBCL. The type information given in the `defclass` macro via `:type` on the other hand appears to have no impact on performance.

```
(defclass class-1 () ((arr :type (simple-array bit))))

(defun sample (inst)
  (declare (type class-1 inst))
  (let ((arr (slot-value inst 'arr)))
    (declare (type (simple-array bit) arr)) ;; 3x running time without
    (map-into arr #'(lambda (dummy) (if (< (random 1.0) 0.5) 0 1)) arr)))

(let ((inst (make-instance 'class-1)))
  (setf (slot-value inst 'arr) (make-array 10000 :element-type 'bit))
  (loop for i from 1 to 10000 do (sample inst)))
```

How can I have the same performance benefit without having to declare the `arr` slot a `simple-array bit` each time I use it? The latter is particularly annoying since (as far as I have found out) is requires to introduce a binding via `let` or similar each time; I cannot just write `(slot-value inst 'arr)` in the place where I need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First** of all, this is an SBCL-specific question, you might get a better answer on the SBCL user list. Different compilers do different optimizations, and most ignore at least some declarations.

**Second**, you should let-bind `arr` because you are using it twice.

**Third**, you can use [`the`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_the.htm) if you want to avoid let-bind:

```
(the (simple-array bit) (slot-value inst 'arr))
```

**Fourth**, if you want the compiler to infer the type, use a specific reader instead of `slot-value`:

```
(defclass c () ((arr :type (simple-array bit) :reader c-arr)))

(defun sample (inst)
  (declare (type class-1 inst))
  (let ((arr (c-arr inst)))
    (map-into arr #'(lambda (dummy) (random 2)) arr)))
```

`c-arr` should allow the compiler to infer the value type easier, but (as you have discovered yourself!) you might need to declare its return type:

```
(declaim (ftype (function (c) (simple-array bit)) c-arr))
```

The reason is, apparently, that SBCL ignores slot type declarations.

Comment: Using a reader was a good idea, but it didn't work for me directly. What worked, however, is a reader plus the following, using your class and function names: `(declaim (ftype (function ((c)) (simple-array bit)) c-arr))`. With this in place, even the `:type` can be omitted, as well as `(declare (type class-1 inst))`.

Comment: It probably should be `(declaim (ftype (function (c) (simple-array bit)) c-arr))`. Both appear to work, I am not sure why. Haven't used that form before.

Answer (score 4):

Adding type information has different effects depending which compiler you use and which optimization levels are in effect.

For an optimizing compiler it might look like this:

- no information: generic operations, reasonably fast
- type declaration available: added operations to check for this specific type during runtime -> slower
- type declarations available, high optimization and low safety: NO added operations to type check at runtime, specialized code generated for this type -> POSSIBLY FASTER

Some compilers also ignore type declarations for CLOS slots. If they don't, there are again two variants: 1) safety means runtime checks added and 2) low safety and high speed means specialized instructions generated

Summary: type declarations may add runtime overhead with high safety due to added type checks. Specialized data types not necessarily faster with low safety and high optimization.